# Django error: 404 Page not found on get method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get serialized data from endpoint `localhost:8000/v1/test/uuid`, but hitting a `404` error - what is wrong with below?

views.py

- from `uuid` in response, get site object

```
class Test(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        uuid = kwargs.get('uuid')
        resp = {'site': None}
        
        site = Site.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
        resp['site'] = SiteSerializer(site).data
        return Response(resp)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import re_path

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from site_config import views

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(
    r'site',
    views.SiteViewSet,
    basename='site')


urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^v1/', include(router.urls)),
    re_path('test/<uuid:uuid>/', views.Test.as_view(), name='test'),
]
```

models.py

- site `id` as the pk

```
class Site(models.Model):
    """
    Model that represents a Site
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True)
    domain_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = [
            'uuid',
            'domain_name'
        ]
```

**FYI** - the endpoint was working when the `views.py` was returning all Sites, but it isn't working when I try to filter on `uuid`.

views.py (previously working version)

```
class Test(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = {'site': None}
        site = Site.objects.all()
        resp['site'] = SiteSerializer(site, many=True).data
        return Response(resp)
```

Error Message on Browser:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/v1/test/7c018183-c952-4040-a450-e3cb58f09745/
Using the URLconf defined in site_config.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^v1/ ^site/$ [name='site-list']
^v1/ ^site\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='site-list']
^v1/ ^site/(?P<uuid>[^/.]+)/$ [name='site-detail']
^v1/ ^site/(?P<uuid>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='site-detail']
^v1/ ^$ [name='api-root']
^v1/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
test/<uuid:uuid> [name='test']
```

Comment: Hi, Ether! As you defined in your **urls.py** the request should be send to your _router_ apps **urls.py**. Please edit your question and provide the corresponding router/urls.py.

Comment: @SvenTUM hello! i added the `urls.py` - is it because the endpoints aren't defined consistently?

Comment: What is the url that raises the error?

Comment: @HuLuViCa `http://localhost:8000/v1/test/7c018183-c952-4040-a450-e3cb58f09745/?format=json`

Comment: Based on the error message, your view is in `http://localhost:8000/test/7c018183-c952-4040-a450-e3cb58f09745/?format=json` (without the v1) hence the 404

Comment: `router.register(r'site',...` → `r'site'` means URL prefix. Did you try `http://localhost:8000/site/v1/test/`?

Comment: @bdbd tried it without v1, still getting 404: `Using the URLconf defined in site_config.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^v1/
test/<uuid:uuid> [name='test']`

Comment: @rzlvmp that doesn't seem to match the url path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### urls.py

As this is a routing problem the first place to have a look should be the urls.py.

Without recreating the app it looks like there are potentially three problems there:

#### Analysis

##### 1. `re_path`

`re_path` is used, a regular Django `path` expression is provided. The [django.urls documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/) has some examples that speak for themselves.

##### 2. the path itselt

The URL path starts with `v1/` while the provided configuration starts with `test/`.

##### 3. the order

As the `re_path` for `^v1/` matches anything beginning with `v1/` the order in the pattern is important.

Anything that should available in that path must either be listed before the regex match, or be registered in the router.

#### Fix

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/test/<uuid:uuid>/', views.Test.as_view(), name='test'),
    re_path(r'^v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: hey there! I updated the urlpatterns to your suggested method, but still getting a 404.
it's odd because I see the url in the list of URL patterns:

`Using the URLconf defined in site_config.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

v1/test/<uuid:uuid> [name='test']`

Comment: Hi Esther! That's my bad, if you change the order it might work. I forgot you used `re_path` which I haven't yet needed/used yet. The first pattern matches everything beginning with `v1/` so the second pattern won't be matched any more. I'll adjust that.

Answer (score 0):

> FYI - the endpoint was working when the views.py was returning all
> Sites, but it isn't working when I try to filter on uuid.

As I do not have the breakpoint analysis for your views.py code I assume that your get method inside

```
class Test(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        uuid = kwargs.get('uuid')
        resp = {'site': None}
        
        site = Site.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
        resp['site'] = SiteSerializer(site).data
        return Response(resp)
```

is not getting resolved by the patterns in your urls.py or the uuid is not getting through.

If the case is former here what you can do is a direct mapping of the UUID inside the get method and avoiding the `kwarg.get()` by doing this

```
class Test(APIView):
        def get(self, request, uuid, *args, **kwargs):
            uuid = uuid
            resp = {'site': None}
            
            site = Site.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
            resp['site'] = SiteSerializer(site).data
            return Response(resp)
```